# Table angular ng repeat category headers

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table that needs sub header when category change currently i use bootstrap as css framework but are there any other css table that support sub headers.

$scope.dish = [{"category" :"italian", "name" : "Pasta"}, ....];

```
<tr ng-repeat="for d in dish">
  <h1 ng-show="d.category != d.category">{{d.category}}</h1>
  <td>{{d.name}}</td>
<tr>
```

Comment: Can you show what your data looks like? Currently your question is kind of vague.

Comment: That is not exactly how HTML tables work. You should at least put the h1 in a cell.

Comment: Is there a div table option that i could use instead?